# How to find out what files were changed after a branch was made in git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I had a branch called master. Then a new branch called hotfix-21 off of master. Then changes were made and committed. Then hotfix-21-2 branched off of hotfix-21. Then changes were made and committed to that. All in all a critical bug was fixed, but it took a lot of changes in a lot of files in a big project. While the hotfix was being worked on the master branch moved forward. Now I want to make the hotfix-21-2 changes into master, but since the master structure changed... I want to make all of the changes myself. The person that worked on hotfix-21-2 doesn't work here anymore so I'm kind of lost with how to make this merge. I am just going to compare all of the files myself and make the necessary changes, but I just need to find exactly which files were changed in hotfix-21-2 from master and then I can begin.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git diff branch_1 branch_2
```

More specifically, in your case, the command

```
git diff master hotfix-21-2
```

will give you the diff between the tips of your two branches, `master` and `hotfix-21-2`.

Comment: Diffs are "pointwise"; no need for the range operator (`..`) here.

Comment: git diff master hotfix-21-2? @Jubobs